# Как передать в Blazor e-mail через адресную строку?

Tags: c#, blazor

Необходимо передать в приложение на Blazor e-mail через адресную строку. Примерно, так:
http://admin.com/requeststatistics/a.b@email.com

Попробовал стандартный вариант:

```
@page "/RequestStatistics/{userEmail}"
 
... 
 
@code {    
    [Parameter]
    public string userEmail { get; set; }
...
```

Но он работает только на одном слове. Первая же точка в адресе ломает схему, и я получаю сообщение

`Страница http://admin.com/requeststatistics/a.b@email.com не найдена.`

Попробовал закодировать e-mail, но это не помогло, т.к. закодировался только символ '@', а сбоит, как уже написал, на первой же точке в e-mail.

Comment: А зачем так извращатся вместо простого `/requeststatistics/?email=a.b@email.com`?

Comment: И как потом в коде получить e-mail в таком случае?

Comment: Прочитать документацию? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings

Comment: SupplyParameterFromQuery применимо начиная с ASP.Net Core начиная с v. 6, а в проекте используется 3.2.1 и поднять версию я не могу.

Comment: Ну попробуйте уже почитать документацию. Query-параметры точно можно использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
...
/// <summary>
////Получаем e-mail пользователя из адресной строки
/// </summary>
/// <returns>E-mail пользователя, переданный в качестве параметра в адресе</returns>
private string GetUserEmail()
{
    var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
    var userEmail = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("userEmail");

    return userEmail;
}
```

E-Mail передаётся в строке адреса ?userEmail=user_email